# Question containing limit,derivative and definite integration

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, differential

> **Problem**: Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ be a differential function such that $f(3)=3$ and $f'(3)= \frac {1}{2}$
>
> Then what is the value of $\lim _{x \to 3}$  $ \int^{f(x)}_{3} \frac{2 t^3}{x-3} dt  $
>
> **Solution**:
>
> $\lim _{x \to 3}$  $ \int^{f(x)}_{3} \frac{2 t^3}{x-3} dt  $
>
> $\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{2 }{x-3}  \int^{f(x)}_{3}  t^3 dt  $
>
> value of f(x) can be calculated using $f(3)=3$ and $f'(3)= \frac {1}{2}$
>
> I tried first principle method of differential but didn't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. You've gotten to 
$$
\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{2 }{x-3}  \int^{f(x)}_{3}  t^3 dt
$$

Now look at the integral. The antiderivative of $t^3$ is just $\dfrac{t^4}{4}$. So your expression becomes
$$
\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{2 }{x-3}  \left( \dfrac{f(x)^4 - 3^4}{4} \right) 
$$

In that expression, both numerator and denominator approach zero. Can you think of a rule to help you compute the limit of the ratio?

Comment: I am getting answer by L hospital rule. i think rule of ratio of limit is not applicable here

Comment: We don't know a formula for $f(x)$, no. But we know that $f(x) \to 3$ as $x \to 3$ (because $f$ is differentiable, hence continuous, and we know $f(3) = 3$.) So we use L'Hopital's rule to get
$$
\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{2 }{x-3}  \left( \dfrac{f(x)^4 - 3^4}{4} \right) = \lim _{x \to 3} \frac{2 }{1}  \left( \dfrac{4f(x)^3 f'(x)}{4} \right)
$$
(I used the chain rule to compute the derivative of $f(x)^4$ here),
which simplifies down to 
$$
\lim _{x \to 3} 2f(x)^3 f'(x).
$$
Plugging in the known values of $f(3) = 3$ and $f'(3) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ gets you
$$
2\cdot 3^3 \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} = 27.
$$

Comment: it would be better if we express $(f(x)^{4} - 3^{4})$ as $\{f(x) - f(3)\}\{f(x)^{3} + f(3)f(x)^{2} + f(3)^{2}f(x) + f(3)^{3}\}$ and then the ratio $(f(x) - f(3))/(x - 3) \to f'(3)$ as $x \to 3$. So that the final answer is $2f(3)^{3}f'(3)$ LHR is not needed. Also note that in the above use of LHR we also need to assume continuity of $f'(x)$ to ensure that $f'(x) \to f'(3)$ as $x \to 3$.

Comment: @Paramanand is right. It's even better if we say this: Let $g(x) = f(x)^4$. Then the limit, in its current form, is just
$$
\lim _{x \to 3} \frac{2 }{x-3}  \left( \dfrac{f(x)^4 - 3^4}{4} \right) = \frac{2 }{4}  \lim _{x \to 3}  \left( \dfrac{g(x) - g(3)}{x-3} \right) = \frac{1 }{2} g'(3). 
$$
We can then evaluate $g'(3) = 4 f(3)^3 \cdot f'(3) = 4 \cdot 27 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ using the chain rule, so that the limit is $27$. But recognizing that interior limit as the derivative of another function is probably a bit tough for a beginning student.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your limit as
$$
\lim _{x \to 3}2 \frac{\displaystyle\int^{f(x)}_{3}  t^3\, dt}{x-3}
$$
which is in the form $0/0$, because by hypothesis $f$ is continuous at $3$. Then you can apply l'Hôpital's theorem:
$$
\lim _{x \to 3}2 \frac{\displaystyle\int^{f(x)}_{3}  t^3\, dt}{x-3}
\overset{\mathrm{H}}{=}
\dots
$$
If $F(x)=\int_{3}^{x}t^3\,dt$, you know that $F'(x)=x^3$, by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Just realize that the numerator is
$$
F(f(x))
$$
and use the chain rule.

Comment: After application of LHR, you will need the continuity of $f'(x)$ to find the limit when $x \to 3$. It is better to avoid LHR as I have mentioned in my comment to John's answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh We can use the “weak” l'Hôpital: if the derivatives at the point exist and the derivative of the denominator is nonzero, the limit is the quotient of the derivatives. No continuity required.

Comment: Yeah, I fully agree. But I would still prefer to recognize an expression like $(f(x) - f(a))/(x - a)$ as the derivative $f'(a)$ rather that apply LHR.